# Extract transaction details from uniswap eth_call event

Tags: ethers.js, uniswap, abi, eth-call

I am attempting to programmatically infer information about transactions being submitted by uniswap.

Say I go to uniswap and try to exchange 0.1 ETH for WBTC. I then inspect the network tab of my browser and find an eth_call event. It has two fields on the body, a to: field (representing the uniswap contract), and raw field containing encoded transaction data as a long hash.

I grab both of those and store them (let's say as

`const contractAddress` and `const inputData` respectively.

I then go to etherscan, grab the abi for the contract and store it as `const abi`. Then I run

```
const iface = new ethersUtils.Interface(abi.abi)
const decodedTransaction = iface.decodeFunctionData('multicall', inputData)
```

Which gives a relatively long list of the form

```
[
  [
    [
      '0xa80964C5bBd1A0E95777094420555fead1A26c1e',
      [BigNumber],
      '0x3850c7bd',
      target: '0xa80964C5bBd1A0E95777094420555fead1A26c1e',
      gasLimit: [BigNumber],
      callData: '0x3850c7bd'
    ],
    [
      '0x7BeA39867e4169DBe237d55C8242a8f2fcDcc387',
      [BigNumber],
      '0x3850c7bd',
      target: '0x7BeA39867e4169DBe237d55C8242a8f2fcDcc387',
      gasLimit: [BigNumber],
      callData: '0x3850c7bd'
    ],
......


calls: [
    [
      '0xa80964C5bBd1A0E95777094420555fead1A26c1e',
      [BigNumber],
      '0x3850c7bd',
      target: '0xa80964C5bBd1A0E95777094420555fead1A26c1e',
      gasLimit: [BigNumber],
      callData: '0x3850c7bd'
    ],
    [
      '0x7BeA39867e4169DBe237d55C8242a8f2fcDcc387',
      [BigNumber],
      '0x3850c7bd',
      target: '0x7BeA39867e4169DBe237d55C8242a8f2fcDcc387',
      gasLimit: [BigNumber],
      callData: '0x3850c7bd'
    ],
....
```

Now, looking at all of those, none of them are actually the LP from ETH to WBTC, their various LP pools ->

ETH <-> DAI, ETH <-> USDC, you name it.

So, how can I recover the original two tokens from the hash submitted to multicall?

Comment: It is not quite clear to me what the issue is. You should probably add more information. But to decode an event with ethers, you can use this code (https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/487#issuecomment-919616975).

Comment: Thanks for that, I've decoded the transaction event (above), the questions is:

given the eth_call event decodes to a call to multicall, how do I recover the original two tokens

Comment: Is your call data you got from your browser correct? What if you try to copy the call data from etherscan and then decode? When I tried to decode my swap, my decoded data was much heavier than in your case.

Comment: I'm trying to intercept the call data *before* it's actually made, e.g the initial eth_call, rather than the signed metamask message

Answer (score 1):

Using as an example [this tx](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf6f3a541e2ab2749c611b7ee1663f0f125a7cb09edc0f20c44cce9a89ab1fccc), you get the inputData for a muticall function.

Using web3py, with abi being the JSON copied from Etherscan for the Uniswap v3 router at address 0x68b...

```
r = web3.eth.contract(address='0x68b3465833fb72A70ecDF485E0e4C7bD8665Fc45', abi=abi)
inputData = "0x472b43f30000...6da0d451c6"
res = r.decode_function_input(inputData)
>>> (<Function swapExactTokensForTokens(uint256,uint256,address[],address)>, {'amountIn': 200000000000000000000000000, 'amountOutMin': 194396059717, 'path': ['0x8AF5FedC0f263841C18F31D9DbCC97A47e1aB462', '0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2', '0xD3cA4151bA451813A3C37e4Ff920406DA0D451c6'], 'to': '0xB31b0F63Ac69a7E05B82840C4A6e10Bb4BD9C3D5'})
```

So res[1]['path'] is what you look for: since the path can be multihop, first entry is the source token, last entry is the target token:

```
srcToken, destToken = res[1]['path'][0],  res[1]['path'][-1]
```

For the token tickers, then do something like

```
web3.eth.contract(address=srcToken, abi=erc20abi).symbol()
```